# Converting values between a certain range to a letter

Tags: r

Is there an easy way to let values between a certain range equal a letter?. So in the following example, how would I convert all values in df so that:

- Values less than or equal to 1 = A.
- Values less than or equal to 5 = B.
- Values greater than 5 = C.

A small example dataset:

```
df1 <- rnorm (100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3)
df2 <- rnorm (100, mean = 5, sd = 1.6)
df <- cbind(df1,df2)
```

Comment: See `?cut` for tips on how to do this

Comment: I don't understand your example data. What is the purpose of these two columns?

Comment: Just so some form of apply function converts all values across each column, rather than within 1 column or a list. Also, I have never heard of cuts and ?cuts didn't bring anything up - I'm not sure if my software needs updating maybe?

Comment: It's `?cut`, *not* `?cuts`. For example `cut(df1, c(-Inf, 1, 5, Inf))` (which will probably need some tweaking for your purpose).

Comment: Yes sorry I misread, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
as.data.frame(apply(df,2, function(x) cut(x, c(-Inf,1,5,Inf), labels=c('A','B','C'))))
#    df1 df2
# 1    A   C
# 2    A   C
# 3    B   B
# 4    A   C
# 5    A   C
# 6    A   B
# 7    A   C
# 8    B   B
# 9    B   C
# 10   A   C
```

Remember to use `-Inf` and `Inf` when creating cut points for your outer boundary. It's wrapped in an `apply` function to repeat the process over each column.

Comment: @akrun In this case, the OP used a matrix to start which changed things